# Check Dataframe Exactly at 10 min interval starting from 9.15

Tags: python, dataframe, stock, pandas-resample

I am stuck on code , where I want to check dataframe every 10 min starting from 09:15.
If I use minute%10=0 then It checks at 9:20 and 9.30 which is not correct.

It should always check at 9.25 and 9.35 till 15.25.

Thanks

Checking at specific interval only once every 10 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are doing `current_time % 10` which is causing the problem in logic.

So, instead of only `minute % 10`, you will need to do `(current_time - start_time).minute % 10`